# May I capitalize "more" in the phrase: Learn more.?

Tags: capitalization

As part of some instructions, the text concludes with the phrase "Learn more." This phrase is also a link. In some cases, I have been asked to make 'more' capitalized. I don't think this is correct as it is not a noun or at the beginning of a sentence. Any clarity of this would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question of preference, without a real "answer." However, many websites follow the principle of using title case for buttons and links that serve as calls-to-action. This varies depending on language, application, and prominence of the CTA.

Generally, if the call-to-action, button, or link is one–three words, title case is preferred. [This](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/call-to-action-buttons-best-practices-guide/) website advocates that practice, as do many UX books. [The world's largest retailer](http://www.walmart.com/browse/tv-video/tvs/3944_1060825_447913?browsein=true&path=0:3944:1060825&povid=P1171-C3658.2967%201126.4711-L0) follows this style for most of its CTAs, including "Buy Now", "Add to Cart", and "Learn More".

Traditional writing styles are often abandoned when it comes to design.